# Using a function in mysql function and passing into database query

Tags: php, mysql, database, function, pdo

I have a funnction called **time_elapsed_string** which converts the mysql function **NOW()** to another format.

How do I pass the function to the mysql function and use in a pdo statement.

```
$lastseen = time_elapsed_string(NOW());
$query = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET lastseen = 
:lastseen WHERE id=:id");
$query->bindParam(':id', $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindParam(':lastseen', $lastseen);
$query->execute();
```

I get this error - **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function NOW()**

Comment: this is PDO, not mysql

Answer (score 1):

`NOW()` is a mysql function, and cannot be used in PHP like this. You don't need to parameterize MySql functions, so you only have to pass in the user id:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET lastseen = 
NOW() WHERE id=:id");
$query->bindParam(':id', $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
```

If you need to pass in a different format, then use the PHP functions:

```
$lastseen = time_elapsed_string(time());
```

or

```
$lastseen = time_elapsed_string(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')); // change your format as necessary.
```

And pass it in as you are in your current code.